# mySQL query in python script

Tags: python, mysql

I need to execute query against DB, to check if file exist in DB and what is file modified time. function arguments are name(file name) and mtime1 (mod time from filesystem). I use script:

```
def chkModTS(name,mtime1):
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='uname', password='pass', host='192.168.1.1', database='newpms')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query=("SELECT mtime FROM pf_scanOrd WHERE filename=%s")
query_data=(name)
cursor.execute(query,query_data)
print(cursor.rowcount)
if cursor.rowcount==-1:
    chkModTS.upd=1        
    print('pole DBs')
    return
for (mtime) in cursor:
    print(float(mtime[0])!=mtime1)
    if float(mtime[0])!=float(mtime1):
        chkModTS.upd=1
        print('need update')
        return     
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

When i run this function, result would be:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

cant figure out, need help

Comment: Try adding port=3306 in your connection parameter

Comment: `cursor.execute` expects a tuple or a dictionary to supply the parameters. In your code, `query_data` is not a tuple. Change it to `query_data = (name,)` to create a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your query string:

```
"SELECT mtime FROM pf_scanOrd WHERE filename=%s"
```

having a `%s` placeholder but not substituting it with any value. You should use it like:

```
"SELECT mtime FROM pf_scanOrd WHERE filename=%s" % filename_variable
```

where `filename_variable` will hold the filename you want to query.

Comment: `cursor.execute` will do the substitution, as long as it's passed a tuple or dictionary of parameters.

Comment: @JCVanHamme I see... Didn't know about that to be honest :)

Comment: Although this is accepted as an answer, this issue might be solved in a way [AKX suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284769/175793) too...

Answer (score 1):

You're likely just missing a comma in defining `query_data`.

`.execute()` needs a tuple as the second parameter. Just wrapping a value in parentheses does nothing, so try:

```
query_data = (name,)
```

to make `query_data` an actual tuple.